# Do changes in slave appear on master (MySQL master-slave replication)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-replication, master-slave

If I create a master-slave replication, do the changes I make to the slave also appear in master?

For example database `example1` is master and database `example2` is the exact copy of `example1` as a slave. I add a row in one of the tables in `example2`, I want the change to show up in `example1`. Does master-slave replication allow this.

Comment: No. Unless the slave is configured as a master too this won't happen.

Comment: No, that's the difference between master and slave. Replication only goes one way, master->slave.

Comment: Any suggestions about how I can make replication happen both ways

Comment: Yes... configure replication both ways.  But that's usually not a good idea, or not the right solution, or can be difficult to maintain.  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, Master-> Slave is one-way synchronization. You have mentioned that your example1 and example2 are identical. To manually check my.cnf files at MySQL folder and verify both cnf files have been configured correctly.

I hope you have configured example1 as master and got an identical copy of that for the example2 and not changed my.cnf correctly according to your required logic.